# How can I find the least number of sets whos unions could represent another set

Tags: math, set, grouping, combinatorics

Lets say I have a set

```
A = {
{1,2,3,4,5},
{3,4,5,6,7},
{6,7,8},
{1,2,8},
{3,4,5,8},
{1,2,6,7},
{1,2,3,4,5,8},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
}
```

We could define another set B where all sets in A can be represented as a union of some arbitrary number of sets in B. For instance, for A we could define B as follows.

```
B = {
{1,2},
{3,4,5},
{6,7},
{8}
}
```

How can I find B given A. I am trying to find B with the minimum number of sets. This seems similar to a lot of problems in combinatorics like the Set Cover or Edge cover problem. But I cannot find the explicit analog.

Comment: Are you seeking the set B with the minimum number of elements?  Because, of course, `B = { {1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8} }` satisfies the criteria.

Comment: Perhaps [hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) can be used with vertexes representing sets in A and edges representing sets in B. Trying to minimize the amount of edges.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am looking for a B with a minimum number of Sets. So your B has 8 sets, the B in the question has 4. I am looking to minimize the amount of subsets. (I know there is accurate vocabulary and definitions to use but I don't know them so apologies in advance if my use of set/subset/element is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is Quine-McCluskey:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm

Comment: While close to what I am looking for, this appears to deal with the reducibility of boolean expressions and looking for boolean sets which cover another set. For instance, they give the example of S = {abc,a!bc,!abc,!ab!c,!a!bc} and the algorithm finding {!ab,c} to cover the set which cannot be used to reconstruct the set S through union operators.